# firebase function admin SDK get current project name/instance

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase Function imported 2 project, one is for production and another is for OTE:

Below is how i initialize it (no problem here):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');

var productionServiceAccount = require('./keys/production-key.json');
var oteServiceAccount = require("./keys/ote-key.json");

var prodServer = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(productionServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://production-panel.firebaseio.com'
}, "prod");
var oteServer = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(oteServiceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://ote-panel.firebaseio.com"
}, "ote");

console.log("prodServer: ", prodServer.name, "oteServer: ", oteServer.name)
```

Below is how i implement it with `Express` (working fine as well):

```
//import express, router, authentication middlewre, etc... i will skip it...
router.post('/createUser', function (req, res) {
    let admin = req.headers.env == 'prod' ? prodServer : oteServer

    let newUser = {
        emailVerified: false
    }

    if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
        newUser["email"] = req.body.email
        newUser["password"] = req.body.password
    }
    else {
        if (!req.body.email) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                code: -1,
                msg: "Email is missing"
            })
        }
        if (!req.body.password) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                code: -1,
                msg: "Password is missing"
            })
        }
        return res.status(400).send({
            code: -1,
            msg: "Email/Password is missing"
        })
    }
    return admin.auth().createUser(newUser).then(userRecord => {
        console.log("successfully created new User: ", userRecord.uid, ", by: ", req.headers.uid)
        console.log(userRecord)
        return res.status(201).send(userRecord)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Failed to create user: ", error)
        return res.status(400).send({
            code: -1,
            msg: "Error has occur during creating user",
            error: error
        })
    })
})
app.use(cors)
app.use(router)
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

You can see I added a handler to route the HTTP request to prod/ote project based on the header

Below is the problem i facing, i dono how to identify the project with the `onCall`/`onCreate` event:

```
exports.newUserNotification = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
   //How to identify this function is trigger at which project?
   //Then I want to write the data to different DB, etc
});
```

Note:

1) When I do deployment, I am using `firebase use <projectId>` + `firebase deploy`, so the function will deploy to the respective project only.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable to know which project is running any given Cloud Function:

```
const project = process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT
```

[Read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) for more information about environment variables.

Comment: works as of July 2022.